# Reference for Analytic Number Theory

Tags: reference-request, analytic-number-theory, online-resources

Are there any good video lectures available on Analytic Number Theory? I have a decent background of complex analysis but I have just started Analytic Number Theory.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1053221/any-online-video-course-for-analytic-number-theory-or-elementary-number-theory. The comment there seems to be something along these lines.

Comment: @daniel I have seen those lectures and I found them quite advanced for my level so can you please point out a source which does not assume familiarity with proof of prime number theorem and starts from the beginning

Comment: You might consider getting a copy of Jameson's 'The Prime Number Theorem' and reading it. I haven seen anything along the lines of your request but it may exist.

Comment: @Daniel thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Apostol's text Introduction to Analytic Number Theory is a good place to start. You might also try [these notes](http://www.math.illinois.edu/~ajh/ant/) by A. J. Hildebrand.

Answer (score 1):

I used Apostol's book on analytic number theory for self study and I found that it was a lot easier to follow than I expected. Apostol's book is excellent for a first look into the topic. I also found value in using Ram Murty's "Problems in Analytic Number Theory" as a supplementary text.